# How to append text chips to text field in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've created a text field using `vuetify` and I'd like to append chips there.

[image: an example view]

The chips will be added if the added text matches the pattern (e.g. start with '{' and end with '}'). I've implemented the part for Combobox when added text matches given pattern new chip is added but in that case, it's not possible to add text and it's not possible to add chips to text-field either.

My question is how to 'merge' two functionalities of Combobox and text-field?

Comment: What you want is not that easy. There is an [existing issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6820) for very similar functionality in Vuetify repo marked as possible future enhancement. I believe if it would be somehow easy to do it with current version of Vuetify, authors would recommend that. Maybe you can find some inspiration there...

Answer (score 2):

without any piece of code is a bit difficult to help but this is what i think your looking for
[Combobox add data with chips](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/#no-data-with-chips)

```
<v-combobox
  v-model="model"
  :items="items"
  :search-input.sync="search"
  hide-selected
  hint="Maximum of 5 tags"
  label="Add some tags"
  multiple
  persistent-hint
  small-chips
>
  <template v-slot:no-data>
    <v-list-item>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>
          No results matching "<strong>{{ search }}</strong>". Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to create a new one
        </v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </template>
</v-combobox>

export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: ['Gaming', 'Programming', 'Vue', 'Vuetify'],
      model: ['Vuetify'],
      search: null,
    }),

watch: {
  model (val) {
    if (val.length > 5) {
      this.$nextTick(() => this.model.pop())
    }
  },
},


 }
```